# Linking OSHA accident/accident_injury data to Establishment

Tags: labor

I am analyzing some of the OSHA datasets,  For **Inspection** dataset (estab_name) is available to identify which Establishment/Company was inspected and also if there are any **Violation** *(using activity_nr to link **Inspection** data set to **Violation**).*

I am looking for Establishment Name (*estab_name*) in **Accident/Accident_Injury** dataset to identify which Establishment/Company had accident.

Is there any option to identify the Establishment/Company info here.

Thanks in Advance.